# Can't use Spring-context's cronExpression with ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring, date

I'm trying to get the next execution of a cron in spring.
Previously, I was using CronSequenceGenerator, but since it is deprecated, I'm trying to update to CronExpression. I use a ZonedDateTime as the current date to find the next one.

```
String cron = "0 0 21 * * MON-FRI";
CronExpression cronExpression = CronExpression.parse(cron);
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-04-12T21:00-04:00[America/Montreal]");
Instant next = cronExpression.next(date.toInstant());
```

The problem is that when I try, I always get an exception, no matter the cron.

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfWeek
    at java.base/java.time.Instant.get(Instant.java:565)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronField$Type.get(CronField.java:200)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.BitsCronField.nextOrSame(BitsCronField.java:180)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.nextOrSameInternal(CronExpression.java:264)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.nextOrSame(CronExpression.java:252)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression.next(CronExpression.java:245)
    [...]
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. If I try to just pass the ZonedDateTime (as it is a Temporal and cronExpression.next takes Temporal) I get a compilation error.

```
java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
lower bounds: java.time.Instant,java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime<?>,java.lang.Object,java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.lang.Comparable<? super T>
lower bounds: java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Java11 with spring-context 5.3.20

Here's the documentation I'm consulting:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html?is-external=true

Comment: An `Instant` has no `DayOfWeek`. Try to use the `ZonedDateTime` directly

Comment: What line/statement throws the exception? `Instant` has no `DayOfWeek`, so that is probably the issue.

Comment: A `ZonedDateTime` is a `Temporal` but it isn't a `Comparable` and it needs both hence the compilation error. So it doesn't fulfill the contract. A plain instant is just a point in time it doesn't have a notion of day of week. Using a `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` should work.

Comment: I see comparable in the implemented interfaces on ZonedDateTime: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html
Am I not reading it right?

Comment: Oliver's answer seems to work when I try it. How come you get a compile error? Can you try again? If it still gives you an error, try compiling Oliver's code in a new empty project and go from there.

Comment: @M.Deinum in what way is ZonedDateTime not a Comparable?

Comment: Hmm not sure which version I was looking at, but I had one which didn't implement `Comparable`... Weird.

Comment: I was looking at the source and it implements `Comparable` through `ChronoZonedDateTime`. However that actually breaks as the `Comparable` is for `Comparable<ChronoZonedDateTime>` as `T` resolved to `ZonedDateTime`. So it probably has to do with the hierarchy of the `ZonedDateTime` (or the generic declaration of the `next` method) that it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an OffsetDateTime instead of ZonedDateTime solved the problem, but I'm still not sure why. Maybe there's a problem  in the implementation of CronExpression?

Trying to skip the conversion to Instant, with ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime resulted in a compilation error. It worked with OffsetDateTime, though.

Comment: please read my answer. It answers your confusion here.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, `Instant` has no `DayOfWeek`.

```java
String cron = "0 0 21 * * MON-FRI";
CronExpression cronExpression = CronExpression.parse(cron);
ZonedDateTime next = cronExpression.next(ZonedDateTime.now());
```